# Jbuilder turning & into \u0026

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

I have a jbuilder template which makes a json representation of one of my models like this:

```
json.(model, :id, :field1, :field2, :url)
```

the url includes "&"s if I just access the field from the console, but when jbuilder converts it to json the result replaces all of the "&" with \u0026 which while it is the unicode for an ampersand does work for me.

Is there a way I can get jbuilder to stop messing with my ampersands? thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So it turns out that once I parse the JSON on the other side the \u0026s get turned back into & so it doesnt actually matter

Comment: I'd like to see the answer for the original question. How can we get jbuilder to not escaping the ampersand?